# Rails callback that covers creation & destroy events?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

Which Rails callback will be triggered on the event that either the record is going to be created or destroyed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're referring to the use of ActiveRecord (the default ORM for Rails) the callbacks you are looking for are:

- Record creation

  - before_create
  - around_create
  - after_create
- Record destruction

  - before_destroy
  - around_destroy
  - after_destroy

You can find high quality documentation on the Rails guides on this topic here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html